# Can't get proper signed_request info after redirect within FB Page tab App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Initially upon landing on the app, $facebook->getSignedRequest(); gives me the proper info I'm looking for, like info about the current page etc. But then after clicking through links within the app the returned array from $facebook->getSignedRequest() is different. It contains  [code] but nothing about if the page is liked etc

How can I resolve this? Is it rather best practice to change pages within the app via parent.location.href ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects within your app will not receive the `signed_request` parameter.  You'll have to manage saving that data yourself (in the session variable for example).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping not to hear that